# Getting 'HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway' when running ASP.NET Core gRPC Service with hosting model OutOfProcess on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, grpc, bad-gateway

I have an ASP.NET Core gRPC Service which works fine with the *InProcess* hosting model.

But I get the following error when I change it to the *OutOfProcess* hosting model.

I have to run the service as an *OutOfProcess* hosting model.

Appreciate any explanation or solution to the problem.

##### Error message

[image]

Comment: Please describe your question better so that we can help you. Could you post your code?

Comment: This is the same for every ASP.NET Core gRPC Service project. For example, the basic template when creating a new ASP.NET Core gRPC Service project.

Comment: This is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this. so you need to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool. this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.